# CSS gradient within gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I wanted to know if it is possible to achieve a gradient like that in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHSqk.png) by using three elements.
There are three sections right now that I'm trying to work with:

Top: `background: linear-gradient(172deg,#FFFFFF 50%, #2D1E2F 50%);`

Middle: `background-color: #2D1E2F;`

Bottom: `background: linear-gradient(172deg,#2D1E2F 50%, #FFFFFF 50% );`

I've tried some things like `background: linear-gradient(172deg,#FFFFFF 50%, #2D1E2F 50%, #2D1E2F 5%, #674568 );` but the colors don't match up correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: To achieve what you are trying here, and to make it compatible with all current browsers, you will have to use the CSS pseudo-elements (google to find a tutorial on how to use them) - one positioned at the top of the parent container, one at the bottom, and both having a width of 100% of parent container. Top gradient should be added to ":before" element, middle background color to the container itself (as it is now), and the bottom gradient to ":after" element.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `clip-path` to help you with the white part and then use any kind of gradient:

```css
.box {
  width:350px;
  height:500px;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue);
  clip-path:polygon(0 20%,100% 0%,100% 80%,0% 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible to do the way you want it. I've looked at the image using a color picker, the gradient is going from top to bottom, but if you're using a gradient to create the angle, you can't just change gradient direction halfway. I'd suggest just using the solution Temani Afif posted, but if you really, 100% need it to be 3 pieces and not one, there are a couple workarounds.

1. Have top and bottom triangle pieces be solid color. It won't match exactly and won't look as good, but just adding gradient on the middle piece, it will look somewhat close enough.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 365px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFFFF 50%, #674568 50%);
}

.mid {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#674568, #2d1e2f);
}

.bot {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#2d1e2f 50%, #FFFFFF 50% );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="bot"></div>
</div>
```

2. Apply the solution Temani Afif posted, but on separate parts

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 365px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#674568, #5f4060);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.bot {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#352337, #2d1e2f);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);
}

.mid {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#5f4060, #352337);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="bot"></div>
</div>
```

Sounds like a lot of unnecessary work so just stick with a single div, for your own sanity's sake.